# How to return 0 if a count is null in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a query which I am trying to get to return 0 if there is no count for the selected status. However, I am getting a syntax error when I run this near the from and am unsure where the brackets need to be in order for this to work.

My Query is as follows:

```
SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(t.id), 0) ticketCount, sn.status, statusName
FROM ticket t, status_name sn
WHERE date(t.create_date) = '2015-06-05' AND t.id = sn.id AND sn.status IN ('NEW', 'NEW - Auto Generated')
GROUP BY statusName;
```

I have read around and some people are saying that `IFNULL` is not possible on counts while others say it is. Any insight would be great!

Comment: The following: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from ticket t, status_name sn where date(t.create_date) = ? and t.id = sn.id and sn.status in ('NEW', 'NEW - Auto Generated') group by statusName

Comment: How are you running this query?  Are you calling `query()` or `prepare()`?

Comment: I'm just running it at the command line on mysql server

Comment: Then you're gonna have to replace the `?` with a value.  That's just a placeholder when doing prepared statements.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned, I am replacing that with an actual date. The query works fine without the ifnull, its since I introduced that it is causing errors.

Comment: Edit your question with the actual query you are running. It is possible that you are using the date without the quotes.

Comment: I have edited the query to show the date.

Comment: See here. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcb16/12102/0 . `count(column)` can never be `NULL`

Comment: The query looks fine to me. Can you recreate the error in SQL Fiddle?

Comment: what is the version of mysql you are using ?